# can i get only one project from remote git repo to my existing workspace?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

i am using eclipse luna with egit.
I have a remote repo and have a local repo...

remote repo is having say 10 projects..... i clond it to local, imported all projects to eclipse....

But I accidently deleted one project with its content from disk from my local repo.... so now i have only 9 projects in local, but remote has 10.

actual remote repo is very big and has many projects (10 was just example. but deleted project is surely just one).

so i would like to know if i can get only one project from remote to local and then import it in my workspce?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you haven't made any commits since accidentally deleting the project you should be able to "undo" the delete through git.  `git checkout -- <path to deleted project>` should do it.

Comment: @R0MANARMY i work in team and we r at diff diff locations with limited internet bandwidth..... and my team mates have made changes.... so i wanted to save bandwidth..... infact its almost impossible to mail because of its huge size!

Comment: I think the cleanest solution is to make one repository per project but I don't know how achievable that is for your team. It takes some effort to setup and let all team members get the right configuration again.